# Segfault while using mmap in C for reading binary files

Tags: c, binaryfiles, mmap

I am trying to use mmap in C just to see how it exactly works. Currently I am try to read a binary file byte by byte using mmap. My code is like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>    

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd;
    char *data;

    for ( int i = 1; i<argc; i++)
    {

        if(strcmp(argv[i],"-i")==0)
            fd = open(argv[i+1],O_RDONLY);
    }

    data = mmap(NULL, 4000, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 8000);
    int i = 0;
    notation = data [i];
    // ......

}
```

My problem occurs when I try notation = data[0] and I get a segfault . I am sure that the first byte in the binary file is a character as well. My for loop checks if there is an -i flag while compiling , if there is the next argument should be the file name.

Comment: Are you sure the file is at least 8000 bytes in size? Also, the man page says "offset must be a multiple of the page size as returned by sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)." As minor asides, you should initialize fd to -1 in case the user doesn't specify the -i parameter and the for loop should loop until argc-1 because otherwise you'd access argv beyond what was passed in if the user specified -i as the last parameter.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that mmap fails because the offset is not a multiple of page size. You can test this with perror and see that the problem is an invalid argument. If you write:

```
data = mmap(NULL, 4000, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 8000);
perror("Error");
```

At least on my OS X the following error is printed:

Error: Invalid argument

Changing offset from 8000 to 4096 or 8192 works. 6144 doesn't, so it has to be a multiple of 4096 on this platform. Incidentally,

```
printf("%d\n",getpagesize());
```

prints 4096. You should round your offset down to nearest multiple of this for mmap and add the remainder to i when accessing the area. Of course, get the page size for your particular platform from that function. It's probably defined in unistd.h, which you already declared.

Here's how to handle the offset correctly and deal with possible errors. It prints the byte at position 8000:

```
int offset = 8000;
int pageoffset = offset % getpagesize();

data = mmap(NULL, 4000 + pageoffset, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, offset - pageoffset);
if ( data == MAP_FAILED ) {
    perror ( "mmap" );
    exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
i = 0;
printf("%c\n",data [i + pageoffset]);
```

Comment: SO after doing all of this, I still end up with data being empty. But the size of my bin file is 16MB. ANy thoughts ?

Comment: What are you doing with data afterwards? I noticed pageoffset also has to be added to the length 4000. With the current code you should be able to access bytes 8000 to 11999.

Comment: I am trying to access the data in the binary file and print them out. The format of each 22 bytes in the binary file is <char unsigned int char char[4] unsigned int double> so I am trying to print that first character. right now i have data = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 3*4096);

Comment: How do you get the length of data? Unless the file itself contains some length field, there shouldn't be any length you can read other than the file size. Also, are you sure your offset is divisible by 22?

Comment: i just did strlen(data) it returned 0. Why should it be divisible by 22 ? The size of my file is 16 MB. So shouldn it process from 0 to 4096*3 bytes ?

Comment: If it's split into fields of size 22 and you access it at offset 3*4096, you're going to be starting at byte 12 of field number 558, which is part of an unsigned int. You can't use strlen because it's not a string. You'd only get the offset of the next zero byte. Such a byte may not even exist if you're unlucky, and the program would crash.

I think you want to say: data = mmap(NULL, 3*4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

Then you'd be accessing the first 3*4096 bytes from the start of the file. Now you start in the middle of it, not aligned to a field.

Comment: SO if I wanna start from byte 0, how would I do so ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10098/discussion-between-jjrv-and-user1320912)