# reading file with mmap starting at 0x123456789 location

Tags: c, binaryfiles, mmap

I tried using mmap like this:

```
off_t offset = 0x123456789;
long pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
int pageoffset = offset % pagesize;


//Open file, get file descriptor
fd = open("./test", O_RDONLY);
map_main = mmap(NULL, 106 + pageoffset, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC,
                    MAP_SHARED, fd, offset - pageoffset);
```

Not behaving as expected.

Am I doing right, for reading file from specific location?
Reference: [Segfault while using mmap in C for reading binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164364/segfault-while-using-mmap-in-c-for-reading-binary-files)

Comment: Q: Why don't you just map the file, *then* take an offset from "0"????

Comment: I want to read starting at 0x123456789 ... didn't get it what are you trying to say..

Comment: You've got 4 billion choices.  Why on earth did you pick the wrong one?

Comment: @HansPassant please elaborate!

Comment: When you ask about something "not behaving as expected", it would be a good idea to actually describe the _actual_ behavior and the _wanted_ behavior.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I was getting Illegal instruction/Bus error. And expected: should run my binary file. But I solved that. Thanks!